# Coding with Python + Kivy - Desktop Application Interface

Tags: python, user-interface, interface, kivy

I've beeing coding applications for years using C# and Delphi. And one of the greatest things of those languages, in my opinion, was how easy it was to code the interface - you could grab the buttons, make the rectangles and etc, all using the mouse, dragging the squares.

Now I'm interested in Kivy, using Python. Can I construct the desktop interface just like Delphi, using the mouse and making the layout easily, or is the interface made only through coding?

Thanks for the patience, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use kivy I suggest that you learn [Kv Language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) which is a simple language to design the UI for kivy.

`.kv` file example:

```
<MyWidget>:
    label_widget: label_widget
    Button:
        text: 'Add Button'
        on_press: root.add_widget(label_widget)
    Button:
        text: 'Remove Button'
        on_press: root.remove_widget(label_widget)
    Label:
        id: label_widget
        text: 'widget'
```

There is however a [Kivy Designer](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer) which you can use to design the UI but it is still at alpha stage and not perfect yet.

> **WARNING:** This project is at an unstable alpha stage and is not yet
>   suitable for general use. Contributions are welcome.
>
> Kivy Designer is Kivy's tool for designing graphical user interfaces
>   (GUIs) from Kivy Widgets. You can compose and customize widgets, and
>   test them. It is completely written in Python using Kivy.

So if it doesn't do what you want, you can create a simple UI and have a look at the generated code so you get an idea of how the UI is written in python.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I'll take a look at both!

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to [Accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find it useful :-)